# Highcharts tooltip is not working for large data

Tags: highcharts

Need your help.
I am using Highcharts to generate graphs in that I am facing following issue. For large data, tooltip is not working for the first time. after i zoom in, the tooltip is working as expected.Please help. following is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/615Lfz15/

$(document).ready(function() { 
                           var data1 =[{"maximumLean":4.7,"usl":5.5,"framesFlag":0,"emptyConesFlag":0,"ninetyFivePFlag":0,"inSpec":100.0,"arrow":0,"ninetyFivePValue":0.3,"mean":4.5,"meanFlag":0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01","conesFlag":0,"targetSpec":4.5,"cpm":54.0,"emptyCone":13.7,"ninetyPFlag":0,"lsl":3.5,"minimumLean":4.2,"sampleSize":30,"ninetyPValue":0.2,"sd":0.1,"fpm":46.6,"fc":466,"lean":3.8,"median":4.5,"medianFlag":0,"inspecFlag":0,"cl":4.5,"sdFlag":0,"cc":540},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":5.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":5.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:00:01"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":5.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":6.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":5.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":5.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:01:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":3.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":5.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":5.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":5.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:01"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":5.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":5.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":5.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":3.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":6.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":3.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":3.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":3.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:02:02"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":3.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":3.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":3.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":3.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:01"},{"lean":5.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:02"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:02"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:02"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:02"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:02"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:02"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:02"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:02"},{"lean":5.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:03:02"},{"lean":5.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":3.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":3.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":3.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:04:02"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":3.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":5.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":3.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":6.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:05:02"},{"lean":3.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":5.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":5.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":3.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":5.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:06:02"},{"lean":2.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":5.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":3.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":5.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":3.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":5.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":5.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":5.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:07:02"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":3.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":6.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":3.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":3.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":3.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":3.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:08:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":5.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":4.8,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":5.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":3.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":3.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":3.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":3.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":3.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":4.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":5.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:01"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":3.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.0,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":3.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":5.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.7,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":5.6,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.5,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":5.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":5.1,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.2,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":5.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":3.9,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":5.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":4.4,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"lean":3.3,"addDate":"08-12-2014 10:09:02"},{"start":"08-12-2014  10:00:00","end":"08-12-2014  10:10:00"}];

```
                       var x=1;
                        var dataofHighChart = [];
                            var meandataofHighChart = 0;


                       for(var event in data1){
                var dataCopy = data1[event];

                if(x==1){
                                meandataofHighChart =(dataCopy.mean);
                                console.info(meandataofHighChart);
                            }

                  dataofHighChart.push({
                        y:dataCopy.lean,
                        dateVal:dataCopy.addDate
                    });

            x++;
            }

                    var qaChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                            chart: {
                                zoomType: "x",
                                renderTo: 'chart_div', // like 

                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'QA Chart', style: { "font-weight": "bold","font-size": "16px;"},
                                x: -20 //center
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                floor: 1,
                                allowDecimals:false,
                               title: {
                                    text: 'Frame Number',style: { "font-weight": "bold","font-size": "14px;"}
                                }
                            },  
                            plotOptions: {
                                line: {
                                    turboThreshold: x   
                                }
                        },
                            tooltip: {
                                  formatter: function () {
                                    return 'Frame Number : '+this.point.x+'<br/> % Lean : '+this.point.y+ ' % <br/> Added Date : '+this.point.dateVal;
                                }
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: '% Lean',style: { "font-weight": "bold","font-size": "14px;"}
                                },
                                plotLines: [{
                                            value:meandataofHighChart,
                                            color: 'red',
                                            width:2,
                                            zIndex:4,
                                            label:{text:''}}]
                            },
                        series: [{
                            name: '% Lean',
                            data: dataofHighChart
                        }]
                    });

                       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in you loop you push a object with `undefined` point (y value) so you receive and error in highcharts (wrong path of line). Only what you need is add a condition which check a value of pushed y param.

```
  if(dataCopy.lean!==UNDEFINED) {
       dataofHighChart.push({
           y: dataCopy.lean,
           dateVal: dataCopy.addDate
       });
  }
```

Correct example: http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/615Lfz15/1/